# How to read the attribute of a child node within a node?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm trying to read an [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file and I want to do this:

1. A `ComboBox`which will show all the vegetable names in the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml).
2. After selecting a vegetable, the second `ComboBox` will show the recipe names in the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) that could use the vegetable selected in the first `ComboBox` for cooking.
3. Last, with a OK button, the selected recipe will read the file path which leads to the recipe.

### XML I wrote

```
<Vegetables>
    <vegetable name="Carrot">
        <recipe name="ABCrecipe">
            <FilePath>C:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
        <recipe name="DEFrecipe">
            <FilePath>D:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>   
    </vegetable>
    <vegetable name="Potato">
        <recipe name="CBArecipe">
            <FilePath>E:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
            <recipe name"FEDrecipe">
            <FilePath>F:\\</FilePath>
        </recipe>
    </vegetable>
</Vegetables>
```

## C# code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    xDoc.Load("Recipe_List.xml");
}

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlNodeList vegetables = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Vegetable");
    for (int i = 0; i < vegetables.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(vegetables[i].Attributes["name"].InnerText);
    }
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I'm lost at this place.
}
```

The first `ComboBox` is now able to display the vegetable names, but how do I make the 2nd `ComboBox` to read the recipes according to the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the following Xpath and then get the recipe for the vegetable

```
string xpath = string.Format("//vegetable[@name='{0}']/recipe",comboboxSelectedItem);
var selectedVegetableRecipe = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

However, as Ondrej Tucny pointed out, during the application start you can cache the xml document in a static XMLDocument and then use it the code to avoid performance overhead for each call.

Comment: Do you mean like this? I'm quite new to C# and not very familiar with it.

Comment: yes , in place of `comboboxSelectedItem`, you will put your value. This will perform a search and will get you the recipe for the selected variable. Please try this and post your update here.

Comment: good to know that I'm on the right path, but another problem is that the method u proposed to me has an syntax error which I'm not able to debug. OH NO~~~ stupid me.

Comment: I have updated the post. try it now... stupid me too.. There is no requirement for a quote after `comboboxSelectedItem`.

Comment: I tried removing the quote but what am I suppose to do with selectedVegetableRecipe? I tried to show it with a messagebox.show but could not complie as it is a var. any suggestion?

Comment: you can replace the `var` with XmlNode and then you have to get the recipe name and the filename and then show them in the message box based on your requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30648/discussion-between-saravanan-and-meowmeow)

Comment: is there anyway to display the selectedVegetableRecipe value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you aren't storing the parsed XML anywhere. Hence in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` you can't work with it. You should introduce a private field (or property, whatever) in your form instead of the `xDoc` local variable.

If you for some odd reason wanted to keep going the way you are working with the XML file right now, you would have to lookup the selected `<vegetable>` element in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and then process all its child `<recipe>` elements. However, this is unnecessarily complicated. Better way is to start with declaring the data structure and use [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx).

You will end up with two classes, `Vegetable` and `Recipe`, and use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to *serialize* (store into XML) and *deserialize* (read from XML) you data. In the form you will then work with objects and don't have to play with XML manually.